# Tab visibility with Default On

Tags: tab, visibility

I am currently facing issue where I turned my tab of "insurance policies" object on, but still is not visible. I can find it normally in app menu and click there, but specific tab is nowhere. I also tried to "Overwrite Users' Personal Custom App Customizations" but without any effect :/ . Would be happy for any advice.

Comment: have you added  specific  object tab  to  saleforce app  you are working under setup-> app manager ->  your specific app?

Answer (score 0):

You created a Custom Object and a tab for it, and the tab isn't visible for your Users (non Admin Users). First thing's first, check your User's permissions.

**User Permissions Needed:**

- To create or change Tab layouts: “Customize Application".
- To create or edit Users: "Manage Users".

If the Custom Object is still in the status of "In Development" it will not be available. Follow the steps below to check the status of the object :-

1. Click the gear icon | Setup
2. Go to Object Manager
3. Click on the name of the object
4. Click "Edit"
5. In the section "Deployment Status", ensure it is set to "Deployed" then save

If you've checked User permissions and the tab is still hidden, check the following troubleshooting steps:

1. The tab may be hidden for the Profile. Go to the User's profile and change it to Default On.
2. Check if the Object permission checkboxes are checked for the profile (Read/Write/Delete/View All/Modify All). If they aren't checked, then check the boxes as per your business requirements.
3. Important: You will be unable to edit this permission for a Standard Profile.
   If the User has a Standard Profile, you need to create a Custom Profile and then give the "View" permission so that the Custom Object tab is accessible by the User. The Custom Object tabs are not visible for Standard Profiles, however. Alternatively, you could create a Permission Set that allows this access and assign it to the individual users.
4. If the Custom Object is on the Detail side of a Master-Detail Relationship, then the Master Object is not visible to the user.
5. Users can also modify their own tab settings under the User settings. This could also cause Tabs to be hidden for some Users. Related documentation:  [Customize Your Tabs in Salesforce Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.user_userdisplay_tabs.htm&type=5)